# JDBC fetch size resets to 1 for streaming types from oracle documentation

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

From Oracle JDBC documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28782)

> If a column of a result set is of data type LONG, LONG RAW or LOBs returned through the data interface, that is, the streaming types, then JDBC changes the statement **row-prefetch setting to 1**, even if you never actually read a value of either of these types.

If fetch size is not provided for the ResultSet by default equal to the statement fetch size.

*if my ResultSet contains the streaming types, does the result set fetch size also reset in the next trip to DB? If yes how can we keep the result set size?*

I am using spring-jdbc in few projects does spring handles this?

Comment: You can set a fetch size and JDBCTeplate [supports](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1_to_3.2.0.M2/Spring%20Framework%203.2.0.M2/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setFetchSize(int)) it. The point of the documentation is, that in case of `LOB` columns (etc) this *setting will be ignored*.

Comment: Even if we set the fetch size, if my query contains streaming columns it fall back to 1 right.

Comment: Well at least in the version you linked (Oracle 11) - *yes*. In doubts you can always set the trace `10046` and see the *actual* fetch size used.

Answer (score 1):

If one of the columns you're fetching is a LONG or LONG_RAW then yes the driver will fetch the rows one by one no matter what fetch size you use. In case you're wondering, a "LOB returned through the data interface" is a LOB that you define as a LONG using defineColumnType. There is a connection property called "useFetchSizeWithLongColumn" which, if set to "true", will change this behavior but keep in mind that a LONG or LONG_RAW can be larger than a gigabyte so if you fetch 10 of them you're going to consume a lot of memory in the driver.